# HTTP Request : ';' character in the request URL

Tags: java, .net, http, http-headers

In many websites (specially gmail, yahoo or hotmail), you would notice the URL

is followed is something like: yahoo.com/abc/bcd.html;_x=12323;_y=2322;

what are these _x and _y parameters? How to access them in server side code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are *parameters* in the URL (as distinct from the query string), [this article](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/) has a good discussion, including this helpful diagram:

```
<scheme>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>;<parameters>?<query>#<fragment>
```

Note that they're not "parameters" in the sense used in the Java EE [`ServletRequest#getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) and such (there when they say "parameter" they mean query string or POST arguments, which are different).

This is defined in [§3.3 of RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.3):

> The path may consist of a sequence of path segments separated by a
> single slash "/" character.  Within a path segment, the characters
> "/", ";", "=", and "?" are reserved.  Each path segment may include a
> sequence of parameters, indicated by the semicolon ";" character.
> The parameters are not significant to the parsing of relative
> references.

(For the avoidance of doubt: The term "path" above does not include the query string, see the [beginning of §3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3).)

RFC 2396 is obsoleted by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), though, which [amends the above](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) markedly:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications
> often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit
> scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For
> example, the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
> often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
> that segment.  The comma (",") reserved character is often used for
> similar purposes.  For example, one URI producer might use a segment
> such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of
> "name", whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to
> indicate the same.  Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific
> semantics, but in most cases the syntax of a parameter is specific to
> the implementation of the URI's dereferencing algorithm.

Comment: Interestingly, it's an aspect where there's some substantial change between RFC 2396 and its successor (RFC 3986).

Answer (score 3):

They're just characters that may appear in the URL. You access them by parsing the URL, because they're not regular query string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Those are parameters to a segment in the *path* part of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

The URI syntax is defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) as follows:

> ```
>   URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>               / path-absolute
>               / path-rootless
>               / path-empty
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> The following are two example URIs and their component parts:
>
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>       |   _____________________|__
>      / \ /                        \
>      urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

In this example (`http://yahoo.com/abc/bcd.html;_x=12323;_y=2322;`), these parameters are part of the [path component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3). Essentially, this is just a convention used within that application for it to be able to identify resources.

Generally speaking, although paths in HTTP URIs are often similar to what you would find on a file system, they don't have to be related to the file system structure in any way. This is purely an implementation decision from the engine that dereferences the URI (i.e. the HTTP server implementation and what dispatches the request to whatever will produce a response).

Strictly speaking, the query is also an integral part of the URI (so many discussions you'll find on "RESTful" URIs are pointless, except for some SEO techniques).

Because parameters are passed via the query segment when using HTML forms, many HTTP frameworks expose its content by splitting the query for you into a map. For example, in a Java/Servlet content, the query string (`getQueryString()`) automatically populates the parameters returned by `getParameter(...`).

If you want to get parameters from `bcd.html;_x=12323;_y=2322;`, you'll have to split the path yourself.